# Inserting html with jquery doesn't work

Tags: jquery, ajax, insert, innerhtml

I'm building a simple shoutbox.

Here's the html :

```
<div id="shoutbox">    
    <form method="post" id="form" class="shoutbox-form">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><label>User</label></td>
                <td><input class="text user" id="nick" type="text" MAXLENGTH="25" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Message</label></td>
                <td><input class="text" id="shout" type="text" MAXLENGTH="255" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input id="send-shout" type="submit" value="Dodaj!" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <div id="shoutbox-container">
        <span class="clear"></span>
        <div class=".shoutbox">
            <div id="shoutbox-loading"><img src="css/images/loading.gif" alt="Loading..." /></div>
            <ul>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div
```

>

Here's the js code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var inputUser = $("#nick");
    var inputMessage = $("#shout");
    var loading = $("#shoutbox-loading");
    var messageList = $(".shoutbox > ul");

    function updateShoutbox(){
        messageList.hide();
        loading.fadeIn();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", 
            url: "/shouts/", 
            data: "action=refresh",
            success: function(data){
                var data = JSON.parse(data);
                loading.fadeOut();
                messageList.html(data["response"]);
                messageList.fadeIn(2000);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

But apparently the messageList.html(data["response"]) doesn't work although firebug shows that my response is :

`{"response": "<li><strong>user1</strong><img src=\"\" alt=\"\" >test<span class=\"date\">2010-10-07 19:36:13</span></li><li><strong>user2</strong><img src=\"\" alt=\"\" >test2<span class=\"date\">2010-10-07 20:23:56</span></li>"}`

If instead of `success` in ajax I have `complete` I get `var data = JSON.parse(data);` error. Any ideas what can be changed to fix this issue ?

UPDATE :

Adding:

```
    var c = data["response"];
    console.log(c);
```

Gives me :
`<li><strong>user1</strong><img src="" alt="" >test<span class="date">2010-10-07 19:36:13</span></li><li><strong>user2</strong><img src="" alt="" >test2<span class="date">2010-10-07 20:23:56</span></li>`
in firebug console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nobody else noticed the error in your html.

```
<div class=".shoutbox">
```

Should be:

```
<div class="shoutbox">
```

Fix that and see if your jQuery stuff works.

*EDIT* As mentioned in other answers you should also set your response type to JSON. Which would avoid you having to use `JSON.parse()` on the data. But this isn't necessary given your use of `JSON.parse()` on the response data.

Comment: ... except if there is no JSON object available, in IE 6 and 7, for instance. (And good spot on the class name.)

Answer (score 0):

> I get var data = JSON.parse(data); error

The response you are quoting is not JSON, is it? It's HTML. Just insert it directly and it should work.

Comment: Poster is parsing the response (Which _is_ technically JSON) with JSON.parse() and that makes data an object. Cannot directly append/insert an object with the desired effect.

Comment: @sholsinger aww, you're right, I totally overlooked the `{"response": ` part for some reason. +1 for your answer, seems to be the way to go

Comment: after checking all the answers this really seems to be tho problem. But how can I solve this ? casting data["response"] as a string doesn't work :/

Comment: @mastodon no, it should be okay, I was wrong. The response is okay even though you could change the type to JSON to save the parsing.  If @sholsinger's approach doesn't work, then you need to check whether `var messageList = $(".shoutbox > ul");` exists at all!

Comment: okay fixed this. sholsinger if you'll add this comment as an answer I will grant you with a point. After changing complete to success and creating a variable to store response data all worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should make your call set json as the `dataType`:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST", 
    url: "/shouts/", 
    data: "action=refresh",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        loading.fadeOut();
        messageList.html(data["response"]);
        messageList.fadeIn(2000);
    }
});
```

This gets jQuery to automatically parse the JSON and give you data as the returned object.

This may fix your problem.  At the very least it will take care of JSON interpreting for you and prevent cross-browser issues.

Answer (score 0):

Proper answer:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var inputUser = $("#nick");
    var inputMessage = $("#shout");
    var loading = $("#shoutbox-loading");
    var messageList = $(".shoutbox > ul");

    function updateShoutbox(){
        messageList.hide();
        loading.fadeIn();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", 
            url: "/shouts/", 
            data: "action=refresh",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){
                loading.fadeOut();
                var c = data["response"];
                console.log(c);
                messageList.html(c);
                messageList.fadeIn(2000);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Did you fix the HTML to not have the `.shoutbox` class?

Answer (score -1):

I love to follow up the latest plugin

Why you don't make your response as JSON only and then populate them with the new [jQuery Templating Plugin](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/)

for more information about using this plugin

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-working-with-the-official-jquery-templating-plugin/

Comment: Suggesting the use of _more_ jQuery stuff (_eg_ plugin) is irresponsible.